# Can you use {} and .format to put values into a dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am writing a script to query an ArcGIS rest service and return records. I want to use {} and .format to allow a dictionary item to be changed a time. How do I write this:

```
time = '2016-10-06 19:18:00'
URL = 'http://XXXXXXXXX.gov/arcgis/rest/services/AGO_Street/StreetMaint_ServReqs/FeatureServer/10/query'
params = {'f': 'pjson', 'where': "CLOSE_DATE > '{}'", 'outfields' : 'OBJECTID, REPORTED_DATE, SUMMARY, ADDRESS1, REQUEST_STATUS, CLOSE_DATE, INCIDENT_NUMBER', 'returnGeometry' : 'false'}.format(time)
req = urllib2.Request(URL, urllib.urlencode(params))
```

if I use this for param it will work

```
params = {'f': 'pjson', 'where': "CLOSE_DATE > '2016-10-06 19:18:00'", 'outfields' : 'OBJECTID, REPORTED_DATE, SUMMARY, ADDRESS1, REQUEST_STATUS, CLOSE_DATE, INCIDENT_NUMBER', 'returnGeometry' : 'false'}
```

What is the proper python formatting to do this?

Comment: `format` is a method on *strings*, not on dictionaries. You have one string value in there, that string object would certainly support the `str.format()` method, so call it *on that one value*.

Comment: what is the method to do in on dictionaries?  even a link to a web page will help.

Comment: Why the focus on the dictionary? You have the string right there, just call `format` on *that*.

Comment: I see,  sorry if that was a dumb question, i am only just learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.format` is a **string method**, not a method on a dictionary. Just apply the method to that one string value:

```
params = {
    'f': 'pjson', 
    'where': "CLOSE_DATE > '{}'".format(time),
    'outfields' : 'OBJECTID, REPORTED_DATE, SUMMARY, ADDRESS1, REQUEST_STATUS, CLOSE_DATE, INCIDENT_NUMBER',
     'returnGeometry' : 'false'
}
```

Each of the *key* and *value* parts in a dictionary definition is just another expression, you are free to use any valid Python expression to produce the value, including calling methods on the string and using the result as the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'where': "CLOSE_DATE > '{}'".format(time)
```